# Can I use a subdomain for is.edu?

Tags: domains, subdomain, cname

is.edu requires a new domain name to set their subdomain as domain alias to it.

It means if I want to get marketing.is.edu, I need to register a domain name example.com and then they can CNAME the marketing.is.edu to example.com.

So I can use the .EDU free subdomain from them. I want to know if there is any method without registering a new domain? Because It looks registering a new domain is unnecessary and they should be able to set the CNAME from subdomain to another subdomain.

Please tell me how its possible?

Comment: did you ask them? It seems to me they only need your domain name to verify your website is in accordance with their policy. I guess they will be able to redirect the subdomain to your subdomain.

Comment: As a side note, `is.edu` seems to belong to "International Schools", a trucking school in Sunland Park, New Mexico. I'm surprised they bury that info in the WHOIS instead of displaying it prominently on their website.

Answer (score 1):

It shouldn't have to be a domain.  You can set a CNAME record to any subdomain.  That means that instead of registering a domain, you could get a free subdomain from another source and use that in the CNAME.

Dynamic DNS companies usually give out free subdomains and point them to an IP address of your choosing.  They would be a good way to get control over a subdomain that could be used in a CNAME.

Answer (score 1):

Subdomains are domains. The site doesn't seem to suggest that you specifically need a [*public suffix domain*](https://publicsuffix.org/), which is what most people think of when they say "domain", so you should be able to use a subdomain just fine.

As Stephen mentioned, you could use a Dynamic DNS address.

Another option if you're using cloud hosting is to take the subdomain directly from your hosting company, for example `<user>.github.io` for GitHub Pages or `<yoursite>.netlify.app` for Netlify. But compared to using a Dynamic DNS provider, this has the downside that you'll need to contact `is.edu` again if you want to move hosting companies.